# Silently pass parameters to controller action from JavaScript (without using AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My question might not phrase it the best, but basically I have a table with clickable rows. When the row is clicked, I want it to call a controller action that has 3 parameters, and load the view that is the returned from that action.

This is my latest failed attempt:

```
$(".clickable-row").on("click", function () {
    if (this.dataset.readOnly) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + this.dataset.subNum + '/View/',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id: this.dataset.id,
                sub_num: this.dataset.subNum,
                edit_mode: false,
            }
        }).done(function (ViewResult) {
            $(".body-content").html(ViewResult);
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + this.dataset.subNum + '/Edit/',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id: this.dataset.id,
                sub_num: this.dataset.subNum,
                edit_mode: true,
            }
        }).done(function (ViewResult) {
            $(".body-content").html(ViewResult);
        });
    }
})
```

This almost works, but the header and footer are duplicated because the view that is returned is the whole page (including the _Layout.cshtml). I'm fine with the page reloading when the controller action is complete (I'm not set on using AJAX), but the problem with using `window.location.href = "/" + this.dataset.subNum + "/Edit/?id=" + this.dataset.id + "&sub_num=" + this.dataset.subNum + "&edit_mode=true"` is that I don't want all of that extra text in the URL. I want the final URL to just be `localhost:64692/{sub_num}/Edit/`. Is there a way I can silently pass those arguments to the controller action without using an AJAX call? Or a way to reload the page using the view returned from the AJAX call?

**Edit** Still unresolved. As I suspected, this code also doesn't work:

```
$(".clickable-row").on("click", function () {
    var subNum = this.dataset.subnum;
    if (this.dataset.readOnly) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + this.dataset.subnum + '/View/',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id: this.dataset.id,
                sub_num: this.dataset.subnum,
                edit_mode: false,
            },
            success: function (ViewResult) {
                window.location.href = '/' + subNum + '/View/'
            }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + this.dataset.subnum + '/Edit/',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id: this.dataset.id,
                sub_num: this.dataset.subnum,
                edit_mode: true,
            },
            success: function (ViewResult) {
                window.location.href = '/' + subNum + '/Edit/'
            }
        });
    }
})
```

because the `success` function doesn't pass the `id` or `edit_mode` values from the AJAX call to the controller on the `window.location.href` call (which makes sense--why would it unless you specify to do that?). Also another problem I just encountered is that I'm guessing AJAX calls can't perform `RedirectToAction` calls, because I've set breakpoints in the action that the AJAX call gets from and it doesn't redirect to the right action. So it really doesn't seem like an AJAX call is the right way to go about this.

Is it possible to pass variables to a controller action from JavaScript without appending them to the URL, like you can do with the data attribute for an AJAX call? I'm trying to meet some specifications and the vanity URLs are a high priority.

Comment: What you can do is have the body content in a partial view and use AJAX to return only the partial view.That way you will not get the Layout section.Assuming you are using ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: That would work but this is a page that you can access from elsewhere on the site. So if I did that I would have a view and a partial view with the exact same code on them. Or I would have to restructure a lot of my code to handle that page being a partial view, which would be tedious.